# adding a scale to my ternary condition division result?

Tags: lightning

I have this condition that displays my file contentsize in B KB MB and GB but i'm thinking of adding a scale so it doesnt show a large number .Any ideas of how can i achieve that in my front lightning component ? . my formula looks like this :

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.InboxList}" var="inbox" end='5'>              

<li class="slds-item" >  {! inbox.ContentSize lt 1024 ?  inbox.ContentSize +' B' :  and(inbox.ContentSize ge 1024,inbox.ContentSize lt (1024*1024)) ? (inbox.ContentSize / (1024*1024)) +' KB' : and(inbox.ContentSize ge (1024*1024), inbox.ContentSize lt (1024*1024*1024))? (inbox.ContentSize / (1024*1024)) + ' MB' : (inbox.ContentSize /(1024*1024*1024))+' GB'} </li>
</aura:iteration>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do this in your JavaScript controller. Lightning expressions are relatively limited compared to Visualforce's expression evaluation. The code might look something like this:

```
var files = []; // this is your variable with the content records
files.forEach(file => {
   if(file.ContentSize < 2**10) {
     file.ContentSizeHumanReadable = file.ContentSize + ' bytes';
   } else if(file.ContentSize < 2**20) {
     file.ContentSizeHumanReadable = Math.floor((file.ContentSize/2**10)*1e3)/1e3) + ' KB';
   } else if(file.ContentSize < 2**30) {
     file.ContentSizeHumanReadable = Math.floor((file.ContentSize/2**20)*1e3)/1e3) + ' MB';
   } else if(file.ContentSize < 2**40) {
     file.ContentSizeHumanReadable = Math.floor((file.ContentSize/2**30)*1e3)/1e3) + ' GB';
   } else {
     file.ContentSizeHumanReadable = Math.floor((file.ContentSize/2**40)*1e3)/1e3) + ' TB';
   }
});
```

This should produce outputs like:

- 1.234 KB
- 2.951 MB
- 100.001 GB

...and so on.

Comment: yes this might be a good solution i ll kep it in mind. For me , I did up doing an aura:if conditions  in my component page.

Answer (score 1):

I have some Aura Components that make use of the [big.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/big.js/) JavaScript library  to handle this sort of problem. That library offers similar capability to the [Apex Decimal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_decimal.htm) class, but working at the client-side e.g.:

```
var s = Big(v).round(Big.DP).toFixed(Big.DP);
```

Comment: I did find this solution  :    <lightning:formattedNumber value="" maximumFractionDigits="2"/>  but my value does't work it displays this error : Cannot mix expression and literal string in attribute value, try rewriting like {!'foo' + v.bar}